# Bound on a complex integral using polar form

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm a little bit confused and also a bit rusty on complex analysis... Here is my problem;

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$. We can express this function in polar coordinates as: $f(x) = A(x)e^{ia(x)}$, with $A(x)\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and $a(x)\in \mathbb{R}$. My question is; does the following inequality hold?
$$\left|\int_q^p A(x)e^{ia(x)}\mathrm{d}x \right|\le\left(\sup_{x\in[q,p]} A(x)\right)\cdot \left| \int_q^p e^{ia(x)}\mathrm{d}x\right|$$

I would say; yes. But I'm not familiar enough with complex integrals to be sure that this is indeed the case.

*Sidenote: I define $\mathbb{R}_+$ as the set of all non-negative real numbers.*

Comment: no unless $A$ is bounded variation (or similar conditions) and the inequality is expressed in terms of its variation - also on the RHS we need some type of supremum on $r \le p$ on the exponential integral from $q$ to $r$ not on the full interval (think of an example where $a$ is constant on some interval from $q$ to $r$ and then it compensates from $r$ to $p$ so the pure exponential integral is zero, while the original $A$ is also constant from $q$ to $r$ and then small from there on, so the left integral is concentrated on $[q,r]$ and big, while the RHS integral is zero

Comment: you should read about the second mean value theorem for integrals as those imply results as mentioned in the previous comment (usually they are coached in $A$ monotonic terms but using that BV functions are differences of monotonic functions the result follows in general) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the $\sup$ comment, in my application I have that $A(x)\le1$ and continuous and $p=-q=\infty$, maybe that could simplify the problem? I cannot understand or find what you mean with expressing the inequality in terms of its variation...

Comment: I mean the variation of $A$ - as noted one can easily find counterexamples otherwise if $A$ is continuos but oscillates wildly even if $a$ is very regular; also as noted RHS must be of the form $\sup_r |\int_{q}^r e^{ia(x)}dx|$ as there are easy counterexample; if one knows that $a' > C >0$ then one can use integration by parts and get bounds in terms of $C$ (and the variation of $A$) - for that exponential integral theorems are useful - not sure what you need but those two things (second mean value, exponential integrals) are the only two general methods -

Comment: If you want to estimate integrals like that one, you can use the lemma of van der Corput; see the book “Harmonic analysis” of Stein, in the chapter on oscillatory integrals of the first kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a counter example that shows that this does not holds true...

Choose $A(x)=e^{-x^2}$, $a(x)=x$ and $p=-q=10$. Then the inequality would state that $1.38...\le 1.08...$